# How to Save a Password in Chrome on a Website that Previously Ignored Password Saving?

Tags: google-chrome

On one of my computer's websites, my colleague initially didn't save the password in Google Chrome. Now, this website doesn't offer the option to save a password at all.

I've come across some directions that suggest using a section titled "Never Saved." However, I can't seem to find this "Never Saved" section in my Password Manager.
Also, I do not see "Declined sites and Apps" in Password Manager settings. I see the following: Offer to save passwords Sign in automatically Set up on-device encryption Import passwords Export passwords Add shortcut Use passkeys across your Apple devices

I'm using Chrome Version 118.0.5993.96 (Official Build) (arm64).

Also, I see this item “Declined sites and apps” at my another Mac with Google version 119.0.6045.123 (Official Build) (x86_64).  However, I don't see this on version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (**arm64**).
Any guidance on how to save the password would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First google hit: https://superuser.com/questions/583942/re-enable-chrome-browser-remember-password

Comment: Chrome settings -> Autofill and password -> Google password manager -> settings -> Declined sites and apps -> Press X next to the line you want to remove

Comment: That's what I see in Settings, there is no "Declined sites and Apps": Offer to save passwords
Sign in automatically
Set up on-device encryption
Import passwords
Export passwords
Add shortcut
Use passkeys across your Apple devices

Answer (score 0):

- Open 3 dot navigation (settings menu)
- Choose setting from list
- Autofill and passwords
- Google password manager
- Setting

Direct link

```
chrome://password-manager/settings
```

And you should have at bottom Rejected website and aplications

(Forgive me any little diffrences in name of tabs or labels i use chrome in my native language)

[image]

Comment: "And you should have at bottom Rejected website and aplications". There Is no Rejected website and applications at the bottom.  As I wrote, the screenshot is appreciated

Comment: @Alex added screenshot and "Direct link"

Comment: Oh, I see. No, I don't have “Declined sites and apps” in my Google Chrome at version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (arm64).  But I see this item “Declined sites and apps”  at my another Mac  with Google version 119.0.6045.123 (Official Build) (x86_64).

Comment: Sound more then a bug or something it's sound like an part of chrome got corrupted or something did yout tried to reinstall?

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled and switched to a newer version

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome doesn’t offer to save the password, make sure that the password-saving feature is actually enabled. To check this, go to Settings > Autofill > Password Manager. If the Offer to save passwords option is switched off, toggle it on.

Now, Chrome will offer you to save passwords when you log in to any website. And if you want to view Google Chrome's saved passwords, you can do so by scrolling down and clicking the eye icon.

**Tutorial with 13 fixes here:**
[https://www.makeuseof.com/chrome-fixes-saving-passwords/#:~:text=If%20Chrome%20doesn't%20offer,log%20in%20to%20any%20website](https://www.makeuseof.com/chrome-fixes-saving-passwords/#:%7E:text=If%20Chrome%20doesn%27t%20offer,log%20in%20to%20any%20website).

Comment: The password-saving feature is enabled. I saved passwords for most of the web sites.  The problem is with sites where the saving was initially rejected.

Comment: Click on the link and take a look at number 3: "3. Check Password Settings for Specific Websites"

Comment: That's the point, I don't see "Never Saved" option in this particular version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (arm64).  I see it only in x86_64